# SSRS report with Image

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with External Image box where I gave the expression as like below,

**Code**

```
=Iif(isNothing(First(Fields!FooterLocation.Value, "DataSet2")),"", "file://"&First(Fields!FooterLocation.Value, "DataSet2"))
```

The problem here is, the whole report never loads when there is no image from the give path or `FooterLocation.Value` is NULL or Empty. It should show the report in whatever the case above but with blank image if NULL or not found or path is Empty.

Please help me find the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to add a blank image instead and have that image be displayed when your field is null or empty? So that your report will always shows.

```
=Iif(isNothing(First(Fields!FooterLocation.Value, "DataSet2")),"<yourEmptyImageHere>", "file://"&First(Fields!FooterLocation.Value, "DataSet2"))
```